# Querying, joining and returning ID's from mySQL

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

I am trying to make a query with JOIN that should work as following:

1. Imaging a user enter either a mobile number or name in a searchbox.
2. The result should be returning data that match the search from the two tables below.

I want to `JOIN` and return data where `ID` from **CUSTOMER table** (`id`) and the **TASK table** (`customer_id`) are the same. 
 My below `$sql` query returns the correct task(s) data (`[customer_id] => 5`) from the **TASK table**, but it always returns ID 1 from the **CUSTOMER table** when it should return ID 5 from the **CUSTOMER table**). 
I can not figure out what I am doing wrong?

My sql query ex.:

```
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM customer, task WHERE customer.id = task.customer_id LIKE 5 ");
```

My CUSTOMER table info:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `id` int(40) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `mobil` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Messages` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `adr` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `zip` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

My TASK table info:

```
CREATE TABLE `task` (
  `task_id` int(40) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(40) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(40) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`task_id`),
  KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `task_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `task_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm amazed this runs at all. Let's look at this expression:

```
customer.id = task.customer_id LIKE 5
```

Keeping in mind that `LIKE` and `=` are both binary operators, this can only make sense one of two ways:

1. The equality is handled first, and the boolean (0 or 1) result of that comparison is then LIKE-compared to `5`.
2. The LIKE is handled first, the boolean result of `task.customer_id LIKE 5` is then compared to your `customer.id` field.

[According to the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html), those operators have the same precedence. However, given your result (a single record with id 1), it looks like the second option is actually taking place. Since there is a task.customer_id with a value of 5, this condition passes; the boolean result of the LIKE expression is a 1, and therefore you get the records where customer.id is 1.

We can fix this by separating the `LIKE` comparison with an `AND`. While we're at it, let's ditch the obsolete `A,B` join syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer
INNER JOIN task ON customer.id = task.customer_id 
WHERE customer.id LIKE 5
```

Comment: Blew my mind that this query actually executed at all; guess the MySQL parser is pretty forgiving. On a side note, maybe skip the `LIKE`to as you might as well use equality`=` :)

Comment: @jpw I'm not a fan of MySQL, and this is one of the reasons why (this video covers some of the others: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emgJtr9tIME )

Comment: Indeed, I've seen that video before, some scary stuff... Postgresql seems like a much better choice for open source dbms.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I should maybe also have mentioned that I (beside for some minor backend WP) only have been programming (backend) for a couple of months, so your input is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM customer join task on customer.id = task.customer_id where  customer.id  = 5
```